# Qt designer QLineEdit lost Focus

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

How to know when the QLineEdit widget loses focus, because I need to execute a function before going to the next widget, but I did not find anything that would help me. Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Maybe you need the [focusOutEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusOutEvent)

Comment: here is my code: